# Jquery firing after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on .NET MVC and I'm trying to play iframe video after clicking div(s).

HTML

```
   <div class="entry-post" >

    <h3 class="entry-title" style="cursor:pointer"  onclick="$.Sakla.al('@("ifr"+item.Id)','@item.Link')" >

     @item.Baslik <img src="~/Content/img/com.png" /> </h3>

    <div class="entry-content" >

        <iframe id="@("ifr"+item.Id)" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {

        $(".entry-content").hide('slow');

        $(".entry-title").click(function () {

            $(this).parent().children(".entry-content").show(500);
            $.Sakla = {

            al: function (gelenifr,gelenlink) {
                //alert(gelenifr + gelenlink);
                var ifr = $('#'+gelenifr+'');
                    ifr.toggle(function () {
                        if (ifr.is(':visible')) ifr.attr('src', ''+gelenlink+'');
                        else ifr.attr('src', '')
                    })

            }
        }

        });

    });

</script>
```

All these what i have done so far. It works only after second click on div. So, what am i supposed to come up with ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you have two event handlers set up for `".entry-title"`.

One is inline in the HTML:

```
onclick="$.Sakla.al('@("ifr"+item.Id)','@item.Link')"
```

And one is being set up in the `document.ready` callback:

```
$(".entry-title").click(function () {
```

As **@Sasang** points out, if we look in the `document.ready` callback, we can see that this is where `$.Sakla` is being defined, so the `onclick` handler wouldn't work until after a click.

Inline HTML event handlers (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.) should not be used. Instead register your event handlers in pure JavaScript with `object.addEventListener()` or with JQuery: `object.on("eventName", callback)`

Comment: Also the 2 click reason is likely due to the fact that `$.Sakla.al` is only defined after the first click

Comment: Yes. I'll add that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not good at Js. So, what changes should i do ?

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are doing, it's hard to say. Moving the code that creates `$.Sakla` out of the click event handler and just having it in the `document.ready` code could do it, but I can't be sure that's correct without seeing much more code.

Comment: Thank you so much @ScottMarcus . I will try to do what you said now.

Comment: @Quicksilver - I agree and can't emphasize enough: **"Inline HTML event handlers should not be used."** ... after that, get rid of `<script type="text/javascript">` blocks and move your code into a separate `.js` file.